# R: Error: X-13 run failed Errors: - -I, -O, -M, -D, -C, -S, -N, -V, -R, -Q, -X, -T

Tags: r

```
ts1 %>% seas(x11="") %>%
autoplot() + xlab("Year") +
ggtitle("x11 decomposition")
```

Error: X-13 run failed

Errors:

- -I, -O, -M, -D, -C, -S, -N, -V, -R, -Q, -X, -T.

  ```
  ts1<- ts(weather_15years[,2],frequency=12, start=decimal_date(ymd("1995-01-01")))
  ```

my ts1 time series is just a time series of 1 column of numbers

I really don't understand what is that error saying that x-13 run failed with errors I don't even know.

Comment: You are probably running one or more packages that you have not documented with `library` calls. Bad kitten.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. Otherwise it's hard for anyone to do any more than guess—we can't see your data and don't know what packages you're using